# Calling JavaScript function on hitting enter key in input box

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

Although I am able to call Javascript function on hitting the <kbd>enter</kbd> key. I am calling a function `shortIt()` when user hits the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, `shortIt()` takes the text from input box and makes a request to Google URL Shortener API which returns a short URL, but the generated response is visible for only some seconds. 
I am showing the response in a div.

Seems to be very weird problem, code is here https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3freebucket/URLShortner/url-shortner.html

But when I click on `shortIt` button to short the url. It works fine and the response text stays in the div.

Answer (score 1):

This is because on pressing the enter key, the `form` gets submitted. When this happens you will notice the page reloading.  This is a default behaviour and is the consequence of using `<form>`.  On form submission, the page in the forms `action` attribute is loaded.  In this case the `action` attribute of the `<form>` is not set and so the page you are on is just reloaded, thus the script stops running and the page reloads.

**Two straight forward options for fixing this:**

1. (Simplest) Remove the form tag - it is not used to submit anything so removing it should leave things still working
2. Prevent the default action when the form `submit` event is fired.

   With JQuery:

   `$('#myForm').on('submit', function (evt) { 
       evt.preventDefault(); // prevents form submission
    });`

Where `myForm` is the ID of your form tag.  You will need add an id attribute to your existing html form tag: `<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal">`

Comment: Thanks @Mahout , I just removed the form tag